# Conda python=2 environment uses Python 3

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I've installed Miniconda3 (Python 3 default), and used `conda` to create a Python 2 virtual environment:

```
~$ conda create -n myenv python=2
...
~$ source activate myenv
(myenv) ~$ conda list
# packages in environment at ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.10.15               py27_0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
openssl                   1.1.1a               h7b6447c_0  
pip                       18.1                     py27_0  
python                    2.7.15               h9bab390_4  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
setuptools                40.6.2                   py27_0  
sqlite                    3.25.3               h7b6447c_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
wheel                     0.32.3                   py27_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

However, if I try to run Python, it uses Python 3:

```
(myenv) ~$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:19:42) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

The same thing happens if I try to run a script with Python 2 code from within the environment.

```
(myenv) ~$ python hello2.py
File "hello2.py", line 1
    print "Hello World in Python 2"
                                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello World in Python 2")?
```

I tried deleting and recreating the environment, but it made no difference. Why is this happening?

**APPENDIX**

Additional info as requested in comments:

```
(myenv) ~$ which python
~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python

(myenv) ~$ ls ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 9 Dec  3 22:43 ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python -> python2.7

(myenv) ~$ echo $PATH
~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin:~/miniconda3/bin:[rest of usual PATH]

(myenv) ~$ alias
[...]
alias python='python3'
```

Comment: Try `which python` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: It seems that both python 2 and 3 and present in the environment. Try `python2 hello2.py`

Comment: @seralouk: yes, python2 works, but then, what's the point of having virtual environments with particular setups?

Comment: Your `$PATH` seems correct. Try `alias` now, see what it tells you.

Comment: This question has come up a lot lately. Can you try activating your environment with `conda activate` instead of `source activate`?

Comment: @darthbith, same thing happens with `conda activate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the alias:

```
alias python='python3'
```

This alias will be set somewhere in your shell start up scripts. If you're using bash that's `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`. Find it and remove it.

The alias expansion takes priority over `PATH` lookup (alias expansion happens first).
If you can't find out where the alias is being set, you can explicitly unalias python in your `.bashrc` (or `.profile`, or both):

```
unalias python
```

In any case you can avoid using the alias when you want to run Python by quoting the python token:

```
\python hello2.py
```

Comment: There's no Python alias in ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile, and there's no .bash_profile file. I tried adding `\python` in ~/.bashrc (if that's what you meant), but that resulted going straight into Python 2 whenever I opened a terminal.

Comment: That's not what I meant (sorry), but you gave me another idea. I've edited the answer.

Comment: As it turns out, the Python alias was in ~/.bash_aliases, and commenting it out resolved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for listing all the common `.bash` places! For anyone curious: https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc